# What are Chrome App Packs for Business?

Tags: google-workspace, google-chrome, chrome-web-store

One of my friends told me about Chrome App Packs for Business. Where can I find information about this service? I haven't found anything at the Chrome Web Store. Do you have any experience with App Packs by Google?

Answer (score 1):

Information on the app packs can be found at [Google's Support Page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3134923?hl=en).

App packs are packages of apps that an admin can install for its users. Here are the details from the page on the [pre-installed app-packs](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3134923?hl=en#preinstall):

> You can pre-install apps on your users' managed Chrome devices so that they see the apps from their [apps list](http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?&answer=2589434) when they're signed in to their Chrome devices.
>
> Follow these steps to pre-install apps:
>
> 1. Sign in to the [Admin console](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?&answer=182076).
> 2. Go to **Settings > Chrome Management > User Settings**.
> 3. Click on **Manage pre-installed apps**.
> 4. In the **Manage pre-installed apps** dialog box that appears, select the extensions or applications you want to pre-install.

You can also view a collection of the business apps in the app pack on the [Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/collection/business-app-pack).

I'd suggest reading over the support page to get a greater understanding of what exactly the app packs are all about.